# Amplitude spectrum for simple RL circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, frequency

I have some problems trying to understand amplitude spectrum for simple RL circuit shown below:
[image]

for this circuit in order to find amplitude spectrum of response Vo we write folowing equations:
[image]

base on the final equation we draw aplitude spectrum:
[image]

My questons:

1. To me this amplitude spectrum doesn't make any sense. for low values of w (omega) Vo voltage on inductor shall be 0 since inductor is short circut for DC. What we have on our amplitude spectrum then - high Vo for low frequencies! And vice versa low Vo for high frequencies...how is that possible?
2. Why in the question for n-th harmonic (second equation) the DC component of Vs has been dropped and sumation has been substituted with phasor -90 degrees?
3. In the first equation which describes square wave input signal, what does this n = 2k - 1 means and how does it influence this signal? What if it was n = 2k+1 or simply 2k?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly point out, this is a [RL high-pass filter](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-filt-hipass-l.html) and has zero transfer at zero frequency.  And indeed, the constant term in the input *isn't* present in the output.

But this doesn't imply that the output signal *must* have higher frequency components with greater amplitude than lower frequency components.  If the lower frequency components in the input signal have much larger amplitudes than the high frequency components, the spectrum of the output may be dominated by the lower frequency components.

The transfer function is given by

$$H(\omega) = \left(\frac{V_o(\omega}{V_s(\omega)}\right) = \frac{j2\omega}{5 + j2\omega} = \frac{j2\omega}{5 + j2\omega}$$

where $\omega$ is the angular frequency.  For a constant, the angular frequency is *zero* and so $H(0) = 0$.  This means that the constant term in the input is multiplied by zero for the output.

Setting $\omega_n = 2n\pi$, write the transfer function in terms of $n$:

$$H_n = \left(\frac{V_o}{V_s}\right)_n = \frac{j2\omega_n}{5 + j2\omega_n} = \frac{j2n\pi}{5 + j2n\pi}$$

with magnitude

$$|H_n| = \frac{2n\pi}{\sqrt{25 + 4n^2\pi^2}} = $$

Now, calculate a few of the $|H_n|$.
$$|H_0| = 0$$
$$|H_1| = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{25 + 4\pi^2}}\approx 0.783$$
$$|H_3| = \frac{6\pi}{\sqrt{25 + 36\pi^2}}\approx 0.967$$
$$|H_5| = \frac{10\pi}{\sqrt{25 + 100\pi^2}}\approx 0.988$$
$$|H_7| = \frac{14\pi}{\sqrt{25 + 196\pi^2}}\approx 0.994$$

So, although this is high-pass filter, the fundamental $(n=1)$ is high enough in frequency such that it isn't greatly attenuated.

In the input signal (a [square wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave) with constant offset), the fundamental and harmonics have amplitude

$$A_1 = \frac{2}{\pi} \approx 0.637$$
$$A_3 = \frac{2}{6\pi} \approx 0.212$$
$$A_5 = \frac{2}{10\pi} \approx 0.127$$
$$A_7 = \frac{2}{14\pi} \approx 0.091$$

In the output signal, the fundamental and harmonics have amplitude

$$|H_1|A_1  \approx 0.498$$
$$|H_3|A_3  \approx 0.205$$
$$|H_5|A_5  \approx 0.126$$
$$|H_7|A_7  \approx 0.090$$

So you see that the filter mainly affects the amplitudes of the zero frequency term and fundamental while leaving the amplitudes of the harmonics essentially unchanged.

> Why in the question for n-th harmonic (second equation) the DC
>   component of Vs has been dropped and sumation has been substituted
>   with phasor -90 degrees?

I don't know, bad notation?  Maybe it should be something like $(\mathbf{V}_s)_n$ instead? And add $(\mathbf{V}_s)_0 = 1/2$?

Importantly, one can't add phasors associated with different frequencies so a summation here would be incorrect.

However, one can represent each term in the (time domain) summation as a phasor and solve for the output separately *for each component* (which is what we've done here).

Comment: Thanks for very comprehensive answer. However I am still not sure about couple of things. First of all, as we can see from amplitude spectrum figure first harmonic is 0.5 but the output squre wave has amplitude of 1 so how this amplitude is achieved if our higher amplitude term is only 0.5?a

Comment: I didn't provided the  graph of input signal but I can tell you it is square wave which has amplitude of 1 for T/2 and 0 amplitude for second half T/2. How is that 0.5 calculated?

Comment: @DannyS, are you familiar with the difference between the amplitude of a sine and the peak-to-peak of a sine?  For example, $0.5\sin(\pi t)$ has an amplitude of 0.5 but a peak-to-peak of 1.  For non-sinusoidal waveforms, e.g., a square-wave, amplitude usually refers to [peak amplitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude#Peak_amplitude) which is 0.5 for the square-wave in your question.